# Monolog pushing the same custom handler 11 times in logger service of a Symfony application

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog

I have the following configuration entry in my Symfony2 application:

```
monolog:
    channels:
        - channel1
        - channel2
    handlers:
        main:
            channels: !channel2
            type:     error_log
        custom:
            channels: channel2
            level:    info
            type:     stream
            path:     %logs_base_path%/file.log
```

Which, as of MonologBundle 2.4, creates for me the services `monolog.logger.channel1` and `monolog.logger.channel2`. BTW I'm using MonologBundle 2.6.1.

When I inject the logger for `channel2` in one of my services and I log a message, I find the same message repeated 11 times (!) in `file.log`.

After some time, I inspected the generated container file and I found this:

```
protected function getMonolog_Logger_Channel2Service()
{
    $a = $this->get('monolog.handler.custom');

    $this->services['monolog.logger.channel2'] = $instance = new \Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger('channel2');

    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($a);
    $instance->pushHandler($this->get('monolog.handler.debug'));

    return $instance;
}
```

Which explains my problem: I have the same handler pushed 11 times in my custom logger for channel2. Is there anything wrong in my monolog configuration? I would have checked the code generator for the container file, but I don't know where to look.

FWIW: `channel1` is registered correctly (it isn't associated to any custom handlers).